# How do I lookup the full name of a registered enum type in glib?

Tags: types, enums, glib

I have a number of enumerations that were created via the standard glib registration function:

```
GType foo_type = g_enum_register_static("Foo", foo_enum_values);
```

But when I try to recover the name ("Foo") that I registered the enumeration with, I get its basic class instead:

```
gchar const * type_name = g_type_get_name(foo_type);
printf("%s\n",type_name);
```

prints "GEnum" and not "Foo". How can I get back the string "Foo" given just the registered type id?

Comment: `g_type_get_name()` does not seem to exist. `g_type_name()` does. Transcription typo?

Comment: Yes, probably. Its been a few years since I posted this example. The code its part of has long since been debugged and is working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can’t check your code fully because you haven’t provided a minimal working reproducer, but the following code works fine for me:

```
/* gcc -o test test.c $(pkg-config --cflags --libs glib-2.0 gobject-2.0) */
#include <glib.h>
#include <glib-object.h>

static const GEnumValue my_enum_values[] =
{
  { 1, "the first value", "one" },
  { 2, "the second value", "two" },
  { 3, "the third value", "three" },
  { 0, NULL, NULL }
};

int
main (void)
{
  GType type;

  type = g_enum_register_static ("MyEnum", my_enum_values);

  g_assert_cmpstr (g_type_name (type), ==, "MyEnum");

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your code does give the correct result, whereas my almost identical code in a much larger body of work does not. I'm going to try to figure out why. At least now I know the results I'm seeing with g_type_name is not the intended result. My best guess at this point is I'm somehow storing the parent type rather than the newly created type...

Comment: Your best guess sounds like a good starting point for investigation to me. Good luck!